# how to do if statements with "and" in sh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, sh

I try to solve this problem with the sh and not the bash.
All i want is a if statement that check some regex AND something else. Normally in bash this would be an easy job but with the sh i only find solutions online that wont work for me

First thing i want to check:

```
if echo "$1"| grep -E -q '^(\-t|\-\-test)$';
```

Than i want to check:

```
if echo "$#"| grep -E -q '^(1|2)$';
```

Combined:

```
if [ \(echo "$1"| grep -E -q '^(\-h|\-\-help)$'\) -a \(echo "$#"| grep -E -q '^(1|\2)$'\) ];
```

ERROR:

```
grep: grep: ./analysehtml.sh: 41: [: missing ]
Invalid back reference
(echo: No such file or directory
grep: 1: No such file or directory
```

I also try many diffrent combinations with this brackets but non of them worked for me. Maybe someone can help me here :)

Comment: sh, or bash? Two different languages, and not all your answers apply to both.

Comment: Rather than using `grep` to check the value of `$#`, it would make more sense to do `test $# -le 2`

Comment: (btw, `test -a` is deprecated -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section; note also, in the rest of the spec, that the `OB` tag stands for "obsolescent").

Answer (score 3):

logical and between commands is `&&`

```
if 
    echo "$1"| grep -E -q '^(\-h|\-\-help)$' &&
    echo "$#"| grep -E -q '^(1|\2)$';
```

By default the exit status of a pipe is the exit status of last command.

`set -o pipefail` the exit status is fail if if any command of pipe has a fail exit status.

when only the exit status of the last command of a sequence must be checked

```
if { command11; command12;} && { command21; command22;};
```

However to check parameters there is no need to launch another process `grep` with a pipe there's an overhead.

Consider using following constructs work with any POSIX sh.

```
if { [ "$1" = -h ] || [ "$1" = --help ];} &&
    { [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2  ];};
```

EDIT: Following are not POSIX but may work with many shell

```
if [[ $1 = -h || $1 = --help ]] && [[ $# = 1  || $# = 2 ]];
```

Works also with bash with `set -o posix`

Comment: No, `[[ ]]` is not available in all POSIX shells -- it's an extension first implemented by ksh, and later adopted by bash and others, but it's not part of the baseline spec, and not present in ash, dash, etc. If you want a POSIX-compliant equivalent (that's able to perform wildcard matching, as `[[ $1 = -* ]]` does), that would be `case`: `case $1 in -h|--help) echo "executing help";; esac`

Comment: It's not true that `[[` "should work with any POSIX sh". [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) says only that `[[` and `]]` "may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations (when none of the characters are quoted), causing unspecified results", and at least one POSIX shell (Dash) does not support them.

Comment: @ruakk, indead i couldn't find `[[` in reference however in bash after `set -o posix` it still works

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_04 : `[[` `]]` `function`,`select` may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, bash's `set -o posix` is by no means *strictly* POSIX-only. Indeed, unless the `xpg_echo` option is also set, it's not even POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, and yes, "may be recognized as reserved words" -- that means an implementation is *allowed* to support them, but that doesn't mean it's required to, or that there's any specific behavior guaranteed to be present when they are supported.

Comment: you're welcome, please accept if it answered to the question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for your particular case, pattern matching might be better:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^(\-h|\-\-help)$ && $# =~ ^(1|\2)$ ]]; then
```

Comment: `[[ ]]` is a bashism (well, a ksh-ism adopted by bash) -- it doesn't work in sh, the shell specified in the title. (That the tagging includes both is... unfortunate).

Comment: People still use sh?  Probably using FORTRAN66, too.

Comment: *Lots* of people use sh. See dash -- the default /bin/sh in Debian, Ubuntu, etc. Anyone writing `#!/bin/sh` (and it's a common shebang!) on a script executed on one of those platforms is there. And your Busybox-based embedded platforms are likewise using an ash derivative, in that case for more defensible reasons.

Comment: (Maybe you're thinking 1970s-era Bourne? On modern platforms, `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh -- a modern, actively-maintained standard, albeit one that *doesn't* include `[[ ]]`).

Comment: @Charles - what reasons are you thinking of that are "more defensible" than writing portable code?

Comment: @TobySpeight, depends on what you're compromising for portability. Non-POSIX facilities exist for a reason, and often that reason is not just convenience but correctness. Take arrays -- one **cannot** correctly store a list of filenames in a single variable without them, but you have folks often choosing to do so, and making their code less robust in order to do so. That said -- I don't think this particular comment thread is the right place to have this debate.

Comment: Thanks @Charles; I think we agree.  I use Bash when I need features like arrays, and sh when it's avoidable and saves me writing `Pre-Depends: bash` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your command is that the part within `test` or `[` command is **expression**, not *commands list*.
So when you run `[ echo 'hello' ]` or `[ \( echo 'hello' \) ]` complains error in spite of `sh` or `Bash`. Refer to the classic `test` usage: [The classic test command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#and_and_or)

And the syntax of `if` is:

```
if list; then list; fi
```

So you can just combine command with `&&` operator in `if` statements:

```
if echo "$1"| grep -E -q '^(\-h|\-\-help)$' && echo "$#"| grep -E -q '^(1|\2)$';
```

Comment: Thank you that actually worked. The internet is driving me crazy. Everyone is saying something else xD Thank you